# In a recursive python function, how is the line of code reached, that comes after the line of code which calls itself

Tags: python, recursion

this is my code that I copied from the sudoku solver video computerphile made:

```py
grid = [ [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9, 8],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 8, 2, 4, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0], 
[9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 7, 0], 
[0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 7], 
[6, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ]

def possible(x, y, n):
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if grid[i][x] == n and i != y:
            return False
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if grid[y][i] == n and i != x:
            return False            
    x0 = (x // 3) * 3
    y0 = (y // 3) * 3
    for X in range(x0, x0 + 3):
        for Y in range(y0, y0 + 3):
            if grid[Y][X] == n:
                return False    
    return True


def Print(matrix):
    for i in range(9):
        print(matrix[i])


def solve():
    global grid
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if grid[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10):
                    if possible(x, y, n):
                        grid[y][x] = n
                        solve()
                        grid[y][x] = 0
                return
    Print(grid)
    input("")

solve()
```

I want to know how the `grid[y][x] = 0` located inside the `solve()` function ever gets reached? Wouldn't Python go back to the beginning of the `solve()` function every time it reaches the line above, which is `solve()`?

So how does the function `solve()` run?

Comment: Python does go back to the beginning of `def solve`, except now `grid` (which is a global variable) has a new value. This also works if you don't use a global variable but solve takes a grid variable in entry every time. If your recursive algorithm fails to "complete" quick enough, you will encounter a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somewhere in solving the puzzle the answer to `possible(x, y, n)` will be false for every instance of the for-loop, in this case the code jumps to `return` statement for `solve` method. in this time, the program runs the `grid[y][x] = 0` part!

you can see more example of recursive functions [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/).

Comment: Ohh. So that means that the puzzle is not correct, and it keeps removing numbers it previously tried, until it gets the right combinations and the sudoku is solved, right?

Comment: yeah, it tries every possible combination! based on your computing power and memory it might fails!! but you should try it to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks for answering